# Applications works locally, but not in production mode on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, mysql, spring, google-cloud-platform, vaadin

I'm trying to deploy my application in Google Cloud Platform. This application is built using Spring Boot + Vaadin + MySQL. Normally, when I load my application (database is in Google Cloud) with production mode in localhost, it is working, but if I try to deploy in Google Cloud, then my app is start/stop - information from logs.

I tried using Vaadin version 14.6 (LTS) and newest 19.0.6(beta), but still this same. I was uploading before create jar by mvn vaadin:build-frontend and later mvn clean package -Pproduction but still not resolved.

If I try to start my URL, then I have message with 500 code

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

Below is my log from Google Cloud and from Maven when i make production jar.

Difference I marked as "HERE RE RUN IN GOOGLE CLOUD"

First from Google Cloud:

```
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:44.989  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : Starting CarFuelCalculatorApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.10 on localhost with PID 10 (/workspace/CarFuelCalculator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2021-05-15 18:36:44 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:44.993  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : The following profiles are active: mysql
2021-05-15 18:36:47 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:47.375  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-15 18:36:47 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:47.578  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 186 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-15 18:36:48 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:48.889  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-15 18:36:48 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:48.907  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-15 18:36:48 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:48.907  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-15 18:36:49 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:49.036  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-15 18:36:49 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:49.036  INFO 10 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3886 ms
2021-05-15 18:36:49 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:49.780  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 80 ms
2021-05-15 18:36:50 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:50.047  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://google/car_fleet_management?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2021-05-15 18:36:50 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:50.048  WARN 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Ignoring provided spring.datasource.url. Overwriting it based on the spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name.
2021-05-15 18:36:50 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:50.449  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-15 18:36:50 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:50.618  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-05-15 18:36:50 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:50.946  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-15 18:36:51 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:51.191  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-15 18:36:51 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:51.360  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-15 18:36:51 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:51.360  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2021-05-15 18:36:54 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:54.878  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-05-15 18:36:54 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:54.952  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-05-15 18:36:54 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:36:54.981  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:00.673  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : Starting CarFuelCalculatorApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.10 on localhost with PID 10 (/workspace/CarFuelCalculator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2021-05-15 18:37:00 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:00.678  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : The following profiles are active: mysql
2021-05-15 18:37:03 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:03.351  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-15 18:37:03 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:03.569  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 195 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-15 18:37:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:05.092  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-15 18:37:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:05.137  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-15 18:37:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:05.137  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-15 18:37:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:05.324  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-15 18:37:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:05.324  INFO 10 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4475 ms
2021-05-15 18:37:06 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:06.095  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 54 ms
2021-05-15 18:37:06 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:06.398  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://google/car_fleet_management?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2021-05-15 18:37:06 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:06.399  WARN 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Ignoring provided spring.datasource.url. Overwriting it based on the spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name.
2021-05-15 18:37:06 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:06.871  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-15 18:37:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:07.101  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-05-15 18:37:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:07.424  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-15 18:37:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:07.690  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-15 18:37:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:07.941  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-15 18:37:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:07.941  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:55.389  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : Starting CarFuelCalculatorApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.10 on localhost with PID 10 (/workspace/CarFuelCalculator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2021-05-15 18:37:55 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:55.394  INFO 10 --- [           main] p.orlowski.CarFuelCalculatorApplication  : The following profiles are active: mysql
2021-05-15 18:37:57 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:57.876  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-15 18:37:58 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:58.144  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 251 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-15 18:37:59 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:59.675  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-15 18:37:59 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:59.703  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-15 18:37:59 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:59.708  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-15 18:37:59 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:59.885  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-15 18:37:59 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:37:59.885  INFO 10 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4347 ms
2021-05-15 18:38:00 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:00.849  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 97 ms
2021-05-15 18:38:01 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:01.098  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://google/car_fleet_management?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2021-05-15 18:38:01 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:01.099  WARN 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Ignoring provided spring.datasource.url. Overwriting it based on the spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name.
2021-05-15 18:38:01 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:01.591  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-15 18:38:01 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:01.764  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-05-15 18:38:02 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:02.103  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-15 18:38:02 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:02.352  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-15 18:38:02 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:02.506  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-15 18:38:02 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:02.506  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2021-05-15 18:38:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:05.916  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-05-15 18:38:05 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:05.987  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-05-15 18:38:06 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:06.019  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-15 18:38:07 default[20210515t202938]  2021-05-15 18:38:07.124  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-fleet-management-313720:us-central1:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
```

Locally:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)

2021-05-16 09:07:55.740  INFO 12424 --- [           main] p.o.CarFuelCalculatorApplicationTests    : Starting CarFuelCalculatorApplicationTests using Java 1.8.0_29
1 on DESKTOP-35TA80Q with PID 12424 (started by S.Orlowski in L:\IdeaProjects\java_car_feet_management)
2021-05-16 09:07:55.744  INFO 12424 --- [           main] p.o.CarFuelCalculatorApplicationTests    : The following profiles are active: mysql
2021-05-16 09:08:00.252  INFO 12424 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-16 09:08:00.581  INFO 12424 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 296 ms. Found 3 JP
A repository interfaces.
2021-05-16 09:08:02.961  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://goo
gle/car_fleet_management?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=car-management1908:europe-central2:car-fleet-management with drive
r com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2021-05-16 09:08:02.970  WARN 12424 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Ignoring provided spring.datasource.url. Overwriting it based
on the spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name.
2021-05-16 09:08:03.931  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-16 09:08:04.261  INFO 12424 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-05-16 09:08:05.002  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-16 09:08:06.004  INFO 12424 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-16 09:08:06.483  INFO 12424 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:06.483  INFO 12424 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2021-05-16 09:08:06.710  WARN 12424 --- [           main] c.g.a.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Your application has authenticated using end user credentials
from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Clou
d SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authenticati
on/.
2021-05-16 09:08:10.179  INFO 12424 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-05-16 09:08:10.283  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:10.379  INFO 12424 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-05-16 09:08:10.466  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:10.816  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:10.988  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:11.160  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:11.341  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:11.526  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:11.750  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
2021-05-16 09:08:11.929  INFO 12424 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [car-management1908:europe-ce
ntral2:car-fleet-management] via SSL socket.
======================HERE RE RUN IN GOOGLE CLOUD===================================
2021-05-16 09:08:18.484  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.en
gine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-05-16 09:08:18.523  INFO 12424 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'def
ault'
2021-05-16 09:08:19.665  WARN 12424 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, data
base queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-05-16 09:08:22.587  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/VAADIN/**'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.588  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.588  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/robots.txt'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.588  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/manifest.webmanifest'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.589  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/sw.js'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.591  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/offline.html'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.592  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/icons/**'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.592  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/images/**'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.592  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/styles/**'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:22.593  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'] with []
2021-05-16 09:08:23.318  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web
.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@41e7a544, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7c682e26, org.springfra
mework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3ec7ad61, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@55682482, org.springframework.security.
web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3e2772a9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@340fc1aa, org.springframewo
rk.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@275902e1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3b66ac74
, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7598d675, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3e2c8ef, org.spring
framework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1d06801f]
2021-05-16 09:08:26.388  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-05-16 09:08:27.463  WARN 12424 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please a
dd some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
2021-05-16 09:08:27.901  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for user 764086051850-6qr4p6gpi6h
n506pt8ejuq83di341hur.apps.googleusercontent.com
2021-05-16 09:08:27.902  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.
com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://ww
w.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.go
ogleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth
/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
2021-05-16 09:08:28.122  INFO 12424 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is car-management1908
2021-05-16 09:08:29.713  INFO 12424 --- [           main] p.o.CarFuelCalculatorApplicationTests    : Started CarFuelCalculatorApplicationTests in 35.43 seconds (JV
M running for 40.335)
```

Comment: As I mentioned on your previous question, the logs give no clue, it just looks like your application is killed. Maybe you need to check if you assign sufficient memory to your pod. As an aside, deleting and reposting questions is frowned upon on Stack Overflow, and if you do it too much it might trigger an automatic question ban. In the future, I recommend updating your question with additional information.

Comment: As I mentioned on your previous question (scnr), have you tried ramping up the logging to DEBUG? Is google expecting some health enpoint to react with "starting"-level messages within the first 10 seconds?

Comment: I go message 2021-05-16T13:22:54.046801Z Exceeded hard memory limit of 256 MB with 272 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml. How can i edit app.yaml? I tried to deploy it by "gcloud app deploy app.yaml" but i got error

Comment: Solved. I'm changed instance-class and type F4 in app.yaml because i had not enough memory as F1, propably also my mistake was to not deploy everything from /target folder but only jar file.

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question on SO.  Feel free to write the things up you changed in your project to make it work and what helped you to debug it.